# Image is not saving to Photo album in iPad mini

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ipad-mini

I am using the following code to save image into photo album,

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];  
[library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[my_Image CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[my_Image imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){

    if (error) {

        Failure

    } else {

         Success
    }
}];
[library release];
```

The above code is working fine in all the iPad other than iPad mini.
Actually i dont have iPad mini device. But my client saying that issue. I unable to find the error what actually happened in iPad mini. So how to fix this issue. Thanks.

Comment: check the error that you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Add check for `ALAuthorizationStatus`.

If `ALAuthorizationStatus` is `ALAuthorizationStatusRestricted` or `ALAuthorizationStatusDenied` then your image will not get stored in Photo album.

To check `ALAuthorizationStatus`. Use following:

```
ALAuthorizationStatus authorize = [ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus];
```